# Javascript Regex: Match any series of letters, unless they match a specific sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match any sequence of letters, except if they match a specific, unwanted sequence.

So for example, if my sentence is:

```
This is a cat.
```

And I want to include all letters except for the sequence `cat`, how would I write this in regex?

I've tried `(?!cat)([a-z])+` but this only matches the `c`. I need to match the entire `cat` and exclude that. I've tried with `\b` word boundaries as well, to no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\b(?:(?!\bcat\b)[a-zA-Z])+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iV6mP5/1